Join tables from different servers in codeigniter php
I have two different servers like UAT and Preprod. In UAT I have one table is users and Preprod I have 1 table is admins. I have written code in codeigniter modal below. I want to access UAT server users table join with Preprod Server admins table.
UAT_SERVER123(UAT Server) having users,admins tables and Preprod server having admins tables. If you observe admins table having both UAT and PREPROD server.
Now I want to Select users from UAT Server and join with Preprod server(code executing server) admins table.
public function getAllData() {
        $this->UAT_SERVER123->select('users.code');
        $this->UAT_SERVER123->from('users as users');
        $this->UAT_SERVER123->join($this->db->database . '.admins as admin', 'users.code=admin.code','LEFT');
        $this->UAT_SERVER123->where('users.code !=','');
        $query = $this->UAT_SERVER123->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

Here in this modal function am running in Preprod server and UAT_SERVER123 is UAT Server configured in Preprod . so that am using this directly .
When I tried execute this code in Preprod sever join query also running from UAT server only.
Here Join  query I want to run in self server means Preprod server only. But it is taking from UATServer123 UAT server only. Expected result is join query need to take from Preprod server It mean wherever code execute that server.
I wan tried below links but not finding any solutions. Can any one help on these issue please.
Join tables from two different server

I wan tried below links but not finding any solutions. Have you created a table using FEDERATED Engine on one of your server? Does the data from this remote table is accessible?

I want to join table from Preprod Server Database Table to UAT Server Database Table .

Are you just trying to match up 'users.code' to 'admin.code' fields? In which case why not query each database separately then match the fields from the results after? - This may be possible with some ORM engines, though you would probably have to write custom data-model classes and functions to associate the two data-sets according to your needs.
